# Xamarin : how to load data asynchronously / pagination?

Tags: c#, rest, xaml, xamarin

Imagine I have a kind of 'social application' with the following code, the goal is to :

1 - Load the set of 'Likes' I have from the server

2 - Each 'Like' has a reference to a 'Post'

3 - Each 'Post' has a text, a description and an image.

The problem I have is that

1 - I bind the property "Like.Post", but I wish to download the data in a "async" way.
See the code int the "Like.Post", it contains an await" and it is not allowed.
So, what is the best way to do this?

2 - I can have thousands of likes, and I wish to "download" the set of likes "progressively", is there some kind of "lazy loading" list is able to download/query the data from the server progressively? Some kind of pagination mechanism

3 - Is there a way to have some pagination with a REST server ? How to develop this on both server & client side ?

```
<ListView x:Name="lvLikes" ItemsSource="{Binding Likes}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Label Text="{Binding Post.Title}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Small" />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

enum LikeType { Like, Love, LOL, Sad };

class Like
{
    public string PostRef;
    public LikeType Type;

    public Post Post
    {
        get
        {
            // HOW TO GET DATA ASYNC. HERE ?
          return await Server.GetPostAsync(PostRef);
        }
    }
}

class Post
{
    public string Title;
    public string Description;
    public string Image;
}

class MyPage
{

    async Task InitializeLikes()
    {
        lvLikes.BindingContext = await Server.GetLikes();
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want your data to be loaded progressively? Do you mean one after the other?

Comment: Maybe one by one, or 5 by 5, or maybe only what can be visible on the screen depending of the current scrolling position. Imagine if I have 10.000 'Like' I cannot download everything then display everything. You see ?

Comment: That is not handled from your mobile side your API should support it, where you send the API a set number of feeds and it returns you them, Secondly when it comes to likes and all there should be a property that maintains count coming with your response so it can be used directly and you do not have to wait for it this is more of a API change then mobile application change and secondly what you are doing in that property up there is not possible like that

Comment: @ClubberLang That is dependent upon the API you are calling, does it have a way to page the results (i.e. a way to retrieve the total number of elements and page size and thus page/index option to send to retrieve a single "page" per rest call?